# Uploading images from Windows Phone 8 app to a website

Tags: php, windows-phone-8

I want to be able to upload images from my Windows Phone 8 app, to my website.

For this, I followed the tutorial from this website:
https://vortexwolf.wordpress.com/2013/06/04/windows-phone-select-and-upload-image-to-a-website-over-http-post/

It all worked good, on the windows phone app side. But I have problems getting the website upload.php file working. In that tutorial, the author is using http://posttestserver.com/post.php?dir=wp7posttest to get the response of upload. In my case, using that URL for testing was working good, but when I put my website url, I get no response, and a crash in visual studio, with following error:

```
 Additional information: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
```

This error happens is thrown on this line:

```
response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
```

The upload.php on my website, looks like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['dir']))
    {
        $dir = $_GET['dir'];
        if($_FILES['photo']['name'])
        {
            if(!$_FILES['photo']['error'])
            {
                $new_file_name = strtolower($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']);
                if($_FILES['photo']['size'] > (1024000))
                {
                    $valid_file = false;
                    $message = 'Oops!  Your file\'s size is to large.';
                }

                if($valid_file)
                {
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], '../$dir/' . $new_file_name);
                    $message = 'Congratulations!  Your file was accepted.';
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $message = 'Ooops!  Your upload triggered the following error:  '.$_FILES['photo']['error'];
            }
        }

        echo $message;
    }
```

I am out of ideas, and stuck on this problem for the second day. Any answers/ideas of how to get the website upload.php file working properly?

Thanks!

Comment: What does the code look like where the exception is thrown?

Comment: I have managed to get the error line, and the more precise error thrown:
` Additional information: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.` on line `response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);`

Comment: If you compare against your webserver logs, you should see the corresponding 404, and see what's different compared to where you have deployed the upload half